# Laravel 5.8 - Singleton method not getting executed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am using a singleton function to execute a custom class in Laravel 5.8. Below is my code

```
 $this->app->singleton(CustomClass::class, function($app) {
        $action = new CustomClass();
        return $action->someMethod();
    });
```

However, neither my class is initialized, nor my method is called. Please help

Comment: Where did you put this code(file and function)?

Comment: Not very familiar with Laravel, but on this own that code probably does nothing except bind the class name to a closure. You'll need to use `CustomClass` somewhere else (like as a constructor's dependency) for it to be able to call said closure.

Comment: @Rob I have put it inside boot function of Appserviceprovider

Comment: do you also use the singleton(like @Jeto mentioned)?

Comment: @Rob: No I dont use the singleton anywhere else. I just want it to initialize my app with some predefined config which is why I have added it to AppServiceProvider. $action->somemethod is a call to class function to initialize the app